# Filtering out irrelevant point features in QGIS2Web Leaflet export

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I'll make some simple maps with data-points with **Leaflet or QGIS2web** but it seems like it is big drawing blue transparent dots at the points I have no data. I just want to see my data-points (like the orange ones in the example).

I even didn't find the blue-dots in the js, CSS or HTML code.

I want to make maps with different layers one can switch on/off. For that, I need "empty" data points that aren't shown.
[image: better example]

[image: Example Map]

Comment: Should be the heat-points, due to to many single points.

Comment: no, the blue points are where I have "points" in my data but they aren't annotated as the orange ones; so they are "empty" and should just nit be seen.

Comment: I'll change the picture so it'll be a better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a filter to just show the points that meet your criteria. For example:

```
var cafes = L.geoJson(data, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return feature.properties.BusType == "Cafe";
    },
```

Option 2:  setup a getcolor function, so points for this are red, the others green. Here is a write up and example. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Simple/indexMap3.html

Comment: thanks; I have this:

`function style_152010Ihaveneverridden(feature) {
            switch(String(feature.properties['q2wHide_Negation'])) {
                case '1NEG':
                    return {
                pane: 'pane_152010Ihaveneverridden',
    ...`
                
wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: can I just say something like: others empty?

Comment: A filter would be better, use something like    return feature.properties['q2wHide_Negation'] != null;  or 
return feature.properties['q2wHide_Negation'] == '1NEG';

Answer (score 1):

The blue circles are Leaflet's default style when no style is set in the code. This has happened because your QGIS layer renderer doesn't have an entry for your non-"nit" points.

To solve this, we need to know which kind of renderer the point layer is using in QGIS (eg categorized? rule-based?). You need to add an extra category/rule accordingly which covers your other points, and then style the symbol for it appropriately (such as with full transparency to hide it).

I hope this is clear enough - if you can edit your question to include the point layer renderer type, I can make this answer simpler and clearer (hopefully).